# Error only using JSTL (No suitable driver found for dataSource)

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets, jstl, sqldatasource

I'm using this code in Servlets to use the Database:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/petshop", user, password);
```

And it works fine. Now i'm trying to do the same but using JSTL:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="connection" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/petshop" user="root" password="admin" scope="page" />
```

But the latter doesn't work. I don't understand. Where's my error?

More precisly the error is:

> Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for connection"

Comment: What happens on connection? Do you have errors to trace ? if so please update here.. Add some more relevant tags here?

Comment: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for connection"

Comment: [Refer Here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1404635)

Comment: I have read, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete problem: the JSTL SQL (and XML) taglibs are designed for [quick prototyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) only, not for real production apps. What exactly is the reason you want to use JSTL SQL taglib?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't know this thing about JSTL SQL taglibs. This is a project for an examination. I used SQL taglibs only in one page, because in context session i have an ArrayList that contains banned email. In this page i need to list them and to show also if it is a registred user. So, instead to call a Servlet before to go in the Jsp, i made these simple queries within the Jsp. Should i change this approach?